# Actionscript 3 error 1176 : Comparison between a value with static type Function and a possibly unrelated type int

Tags: string, actionscript-3, numbers, range

I want to make coding about the final score display. If someone has done 10 multiple choice questions and he clicks on the final score button, then his final score will appear along with the description. The score will be made in a range according to the category, namely 1-59 = Under Average, 60-79 = Average, and 80-100 = Above Average.
I've tried coding it but I found error 1176 on line 7 and 11.
Can you help me fix it?

```
finalscorebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, finalscore);
function finalscore(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   multiplechoicefinalscore.text = sumofscores;
   var finalscore:String = finalscore.toString;
   finalscore = multiplechoicefinalscore..text;
   if(finalscore.toString < 60){
       description.text =
       "UNDER AVERAGE."; 
}
   else if(finalscore.toString >= 60 && finalscore.toString <=79){
       description.text =
       "AVERAGE.";  
}
   else{
       description.text =
       "ABOVE AVERAGE.";
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple syntax and logic errors.

1. **Something.toString** is a reference to a method, you probably mean **Something.toString()** which calls the said method and returns a text representation of whatever **Something** is.
2. You don't need a text representation because you want to compare numbers, you need a numeric representation (which is either **int**, **uint** or **Number**).
3. There are 2 dots in **multiplechoicefinalscore..text**, what does it even mean?
4. There is **function finalscore** and then you define **var finalscore**, defining things with the same names is a bad idea in general.
5. You should keep your script formatted properly, otherwise reading it and understanding would be a pain.

So, I assume you have the user's result is in **sumofscores**. I'm not sure if the script below will actually work as is, but at least it is logically and syntactically correct:

```
finalscorebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onFinal);

function onFinal(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Ok, let's keep this one, I think you are putting
    // the score result into some kind of TextField.
    multiplechoicefinalscore.text = sumofscores;
    
    // Get a definitely numeric representation of the score.
    var aScore:int = int(sumofscores);
    
    // In terms of logic, putting the complicated condition case
    // under the "else" statement will simplify the program.
    if (aScore < 60)
    {
        description.text = "UNDER AVERAGE."; 
    }
    else if (aScore > 79)
    {
        description.text = "ABOVE AVERAGE.";
    }
    else
    {
        description.text = "AVERAGE.";  
    }   
}
```